# Как сгенерировать случайное дробное число из интервала?

Tags: c#

Есть интервал чисел [-10.34; 53.44]. Как сгенерировать случайное дробное число из этого интервала?

Comment: `Random rnd = new Random(); rnd.NextDouble() * ((53.44) - (-10.34)) + (-10.34) `

Comment: @EzikBro ответы в ответы?

Answer (score 3):

В C# для генерации случайных чисел обычно используется встроенный класс `Random`. Он реализует несколько методов, генерирующих случайные числа. Для чисел с плавающей запятой используется `Random.NextDouble()`, который возвращает случайное дробное число в интервале `[0; 1)`.

Так как распределение случайной величины равномерное, то мы можем перевести данный единичный промежуток в любой другой. Пусть вам нужно получить случайное число в промежутке `[begin; end)`, тогда вам необходимо выполнить следующую операцию: `RandomObj.NextDouble() * (end - begin) + begin`.

Благодаря такому преобразованию, единичный промежуток "растягивается" до нужной вам длины и "передвигается" на нужное начало.

В вашем случае код будет выглядеть так:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double val = rnd.NexDouble() * (53.44 + 10.34) - 10.34;
```

Предупреждение: не используйте создание множества Random-объектов в цикле или что-то в этом роде, так как они по умолчанию используют в качестве сида системное время, которое не будет успевать изменяться при быстром создании новых объектов.

Comment: замечание про создание множества экземпляров устарело для .net core